# Evaluating relational operator in C

Tags: c, operators, relational

Given below is a segment of code in C

```
float k=0.6;

if(k==0.6)
  printf("yes they are equal");
else
  printf("no they are not equal");
```

The above code gives output "no they are not equal". I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 gcc 4.4

I was surprised and debugged the program.
The answer is no because the value of K is not equal to 0.6. I single stepped the program in gdb and i found value of k as 0.600000024. Now my question is why 0.600000024  is assigned to k and why not 0.6. when I assign 0.7 the k has a value 0.69999998.
Why does this happen?

Comment: The answer is no because the value of K is not equal to 0.6. I single stepped the program in gdb and i found value of k as 0.600000024

Comment: The type of `0.6` is not `float`, it's `double`. There's a duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. If you are working with float values in C you have to work with a set difference.

You can use

```
DBL_EPSILON of the Header float.h
if ((k - 0.6) < DBL_EPSILON){ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you. I will read up more on floating points